# Change label based on selected dropdown [Ruby on Rails 4.2]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `network` it has the column `type` and `number`.

I use this `select_tag` to get a list of all my network names:

```
<%= select_tag('NetworksList', options_from_collection_for_select(Network.all, :id, :name))%>
```

I also have 2 label fields that I want to populate with information dynamically:

```
<p>Network Type: <%= content_tag('span', "", id: 'NetworkType') %></p>
<p>Network Number: <%= content_tag('span', "", id: 'NetworkNumber') %></p>
```

When the user selects a network from the dropdown list of network names, I want to show the selected item's type and number in the fields named `NetworkType` and `NetworkNumber`.  I would like this to render in the view immediately after the user selects a dropdown.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this Javascript in your `app/assets/javascripts/network.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#network_network_list").change(function() {
        var value = +$(this).val();
        var network_index = $.inArray(value, networks);
        var networkType = network_details[network_index][0];
        var networkNumber = network_details[network_index][1];
        $("#NetworkType").text(networkType);
        $("#NetworkNumber").text(networkNumber);
    });
});
```

This will register an event handler that will act when the network selection is changed.  The handler will get the new selected value and look up the value in the `networks` array, which will be used to pull the `networkType` and `networkNumber` from the corresponding position in the `network_details` array.

Now, at this point, `networks` and `network_details` haven't been defined, so you'll also need to include a snippet of Javascript in your view code to do that dynamically:

```
<script>
var networks = <%= raw(@networks.map(&:id).to_json) %>;
var network_details = <%= raw(@networks.map {|network| [network.type, network.number] }.to_json) %>;
</script>
```

The Javascript code uses jQuery, so you'll need to make sure that jQuery is configured in the project.  Check that these lines exist in the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

These lines include jQuery and jQuery UJS (unobtrusive Javascript) for the project, and these will be automatically included in the asset pipeline.

Comment: Looking at the HTML source page, it seems to be displaying the correct networks and network_details which displays the network type and number in json format, but it doesn't seem to be applying those values in the span tags.

Comment: Getting the following error in js console, TypeError: network_details[network_index] is undefined

Comment: @chinm3 If you can place the line `console.log("Value = ", value);` right after the `var value = $(this).val();` line in the Javascript, and let me know what it shows in the console, that will help me figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Also, when I tried console.log("Value = ", network_index); it returns -1 .. something is wrong?

Comment: @chinm3 There was one tiny thing out of place: a missing '+' sign.  I've updated the answer to show the change to include the '+' on the line `var value = +$(this).val();`.  If you make that change, it should work for you.

Comment: Ah yes! It's working properly now. I would like to ask why the + sign was needed?

Comment: The value retrieved from the selection was a string, and the '+' does a conversion to integer.  It was a type mismatch issue.  It was omitted due to a typo, made while I was changing from my working code to the answer designed for your network code.  So sorry for the hassle.